# Python Twitter Data save as cvs

Tags: python, twitter

I'm trying to get certain tweets with one particular word in it. I've already installed python and got my developer access on twitter. I'm totally new to python and I just need some tweets so that I can examine their language further. I got this so far:

```
import tweepy
import pandas as pd
import json

consumer_key = "XY"
consumer_secret = "XY"
access_key = "XY"
access_secret = "XY"

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_key, access_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

term = "WORD"

for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search,
                q=term,
                lang="de",
                result_type="recent",
                inculde_entities=True).items(150):
```

So far so good. When I add a print(tweet.text) I'll get the tweets.

1. But what I still need is: How can I add the users name to my printed tweets without adding all the other information I dont need (like geo etc.)?
2. How can I transfer my tweets to a txt. or csv. ?
   Please, can someone help? Thx a lot

Comment: If you're _totally new_ to python you should do some tutorials before starting real coding. Your questions will most likely be answered there.

Comment: well thx, but I just need some tweets for my linguistics analysis an no deep python knowledge. so I thought someone just might help me real quick since i wasnt able to find anything on google to help me out

Answer (score 0):

look at the documentation for getting the names from tweepy, or even google.
As far as the CSV you could use the CSV module.

```
import csv

        with open(r'C:\yourfile.csv', 'w+', newline='', encoding="utf-8") as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file) 
        writer.writerows(tweet)
```